# How to resize existing SolrCloud with new shards

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I've setup a **SolrCloud** structures having 3 shards. Each shard consist of 2 nodes. One is Leader and another is replica. Each solr instance (as node) is running in the separate machine. Now I need to add more machines as my data volume increases. But if I add new node without creating new shard, it'll simply increase more replica of shards. I want to **create more shards with new machines and the data should be distributed among the shards**.

For testing purpose, I created a SolrCloud with one shard (2 nodes). I tried solr **SPLITSHARD** with solr-4.5.1. Finally, I see total 3 shards (**shard1**, **shard1_0** and **shard1_1**) from the admin window. Now it's showing total 6 nodes.

In the background, it has created the following folders under each node.

node1 :

1. solr/collection1
2. solr/collection1_shard1_0_replica1
3. solr/collection1_shard1_1_replica1

node2 :

1. solr/collection1
2. solr/collection1_shard1_0_replica2
3. solr/collection1_shard1_1_replica2

It means, it created 2 new cores under each instance. But I want to run a single core under each machine.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem and Posted here      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471840/how-to-split-solr-shard-in-solr-cloud

Answer (score 1):

We have been into the same problem too. The only solution I can see for the current version of Solr is to add replicas on the new machines, wait for replication done and delete the original one.

In addition, if you split only one shard in the collection, the cluster will not be uniformly distributed. So you have to split every shards by the same factor.

Comment: Adding replica will only increase the no of copies of the same data. It won't increase the volume of collection. Splitting shards can actually increase the size of collection. I tried SPLITSHARD with solr-4.6.0 and successfully increased the size of collection.

Comment: I agree on the fact that SPITSHARD is the only thing to do to increase the number of shards. The pb is that the new child-shards will stick at the first place on the same machine and there is no way I know of to split and deploy child shards directly on new machines. Besides that, I have tried to split a big index ~100Gb that takes more that 30mn to complete and at the end Solr runs into a messy state. We have to modify manually the clusterstate.json in ZK to clean up the Solr cluster state.

Comment: Ya. You are right. There is no way you can directly deploy shards to new machines. To get more shards with new machines, I had to follow a little indirect way. But finally I'm able to increase the volume of collection.

Comment: @buddy86: How did you solve your problem at last. Would you share here?

Answer (score 0):

Once you set numShards property when creating a collection, your intention become impossible. Other answers are only depicting about splitting origial no. of shards into more no. of shards but the data won't be distributed evenly, i.e. suppose 1 data starts with 2 shards, say S1 and S2. When do splitting-shards on S1, it becomes S11,S12,S2 which data in S2 is much more than S11,S12. But I think what you want is data in S1 & S2 is cut evenly into S11, S12, and S2 where S11,S12, and S2 are running on different nodes on different machines. That's NOT possible in current Solr (even v6) AFAIK.

What you want is also me and many other Solrcloud users want and I think it's a very normal intention. Let's hope future version of Solrcloud will provide this functionality.